# Keep the chronometer always running without a service

Tags: java, android, kotlin, chronometer

I'm using a chronometer and it needs to run persistently until stopped.

The code I'm using below works well and the chronometer keeps running, however, when the device restarts, I get negative values.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("chronometer", MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Check if the start time was saved before
    long elapsedTime = sharedPreferences.getLong("elapsed_time", 0);
    
    if (elapsedTime != 0) {
        //It means the chronometer was running before, so we set the time from SharedPreferences
        chronometer.setBase(elapsedTime);
        chronometer.start();
    }

    //Code below starts the chronometer, after the user manually starts it

    Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //Save the starting time
        long elapsedRealtime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        sharedPreferences.edit().putLong("elapsed_time", elapsedRealtime).apply();

        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.start();
    });
```

Why does the chronometer display negative values after a re-boot & how can I sort it out?

Comment: What do you _precisely_ mean by "running"?

Comment: As I understand, you are using `Chronometer` in an activity, and you want after device restart, if users open the activity again, the Chronometer keeps counting normally?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- as in if the chronometer was started it, should always run until the user stops it. So killing the app or the device restarting should not affect it

Comment: @SonTruong yes, I've managed to accomplish that. Only problem now is that when the device restarts, the chronometer displays negative values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer)

> **Chronometer**
>
> Class that implements a simple timer.
>
> You can give it a start time in the SystemClock#elapsedRealtime
> timebase, and it counts up from that.

The timebase of this class is based on [SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock#elapsedRealtime()).

> **elapsedRealtime**
>
> `public static long elapsedRealtime()`
>
> Returns milliseconds since boot, including time spent in sleep.

Back to your questions:

> Why does the chronometer display negative values after a re-boot?

Here is an example to demonstrate this scenario.

Assume your phone is running about 10 minutes from last booting, at that time users open the activity, the `elapsedRealtime()` method will return 600000L (10 mins = 10 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds). When users click on the Start button, you set that time for Chronometer as basetime and save 600000L to SharePreferences using `elapsed_time` key.

- Right now: `elapsedRealTime()` = 10 mins | Chronometer = 00:00
- After 1 min: `elapsedRealtime()` = 11 mins | Chronometer = 01:00
- After 10 minutes: `elapsedRealTime()` = 20 mins | Chronometer = 10:00

At this time users press the BACK key to exit the app and restart the phone.

The phone is kinda slow, so it took 2 mins from booting. Users open the activity again. At this time.

- `elapsedRealtime()` returns 120000L (2 mins = 2 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds)
- The value you saved in the SharePreferences (`elapsed_time`) is 600000L

Because the value you set as basetime of Chronometer is ahead of the `elapsedRealtime()`, so the Chronometer will display -08:00 and start counting up from that value.

> How can I sort it out?

You can save the elapsed time of Chronometer and the elapsed time from the last time users leave the activity until the next time users open the activity. Then using these two values to calculate the basetime for Chronometer.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="#F00"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String KEY_CHRONOMETER_ELAPSED_TIME = "chronometerElapsedTime";
    private static final String KEY_CHRONOMETER_STOPPED_TIME = "chronometerStoppedTime";

    private Chronometer chronometer;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

        // Code below starts the chronometer, after the user manually starts it
        Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            setElapsedTime(-1);
            setStoppedTime(-1);
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chronometer.start();
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("chronometer", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (prefs.contains(KEY_CHRONOMETER_ELAPSED_TIME)
                && prefs.contains(KEY_CHRONOMETER_STOPPED_TIME)) {
            long chronometerElapsedTime = prefs.getLong(KEY_CHRONOMETER_ELAPSED_TIME, -1);
            long chronometerStoppedTime = prefs.getLong(KEY_CHRONOMETER_STOPPED_TIME, -1);
            if (chronometerElapsedTime != -1 && chronometerStoppedTime != -1) {
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long elapsedTimeFromLastStop = now - chronometerStoppedTime; // Including restart time

                long elapsedRealTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                long base = elapsedRealTime - (chronometerElapsedTime + elapsedTimeFromLastStop);

                chronometer.setBase(base);
                chronometer.start();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        setElapsedTime(getChronometerTimeMs());
        setStoppedTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void setElapsedTime(long elapsedTimeMs) {
        prefs.edit().putLong(KEY_CHRONOMETER_ELAPSED_TIME, elapsedTimeMs).apply();
    }

    private void setStoppedTime(long stoppedTimeMs) {
        prefs.edit().putLong(KEY_CHRONOMETER_STOPPED_TIME, stoppedTimeMs).apply();
    }

    private long getChronometerTimeMs() {
        long chronometerTimeMs = 0;

        // Regex for HH:MM:SS or MM:SS
        String regex = "([0-1]?\\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\\d))?(?::([0-5]?\\d))?";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(chronometer.getText());
        if (matcher.find()) {
            boolean isHHMMSSFormat = matcher.groupCount() == 4;
            if (isHHMMSSFormat) {
                int hour = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
                int minute = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
                int second = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(3));
                chronometerTimeMs = (hour * DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS)
                        + (minute * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
                        + (second * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
            } else {
                int minute = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
                int second = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
                chronometerTimeMs = (minute * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
                        + (second * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
            }
        }

        return chronometerTimeMs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow hats off!!!. This is the perfect & most elaborate solution I've come across on SO. One question though, why are we not using onCreate to get & set the correct time again, onStart gets called after it and I guess it would have some milliseconds difference.

Comment: @Boron You're right, you can move that code to `onCreate()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the `elapsedMillis` into shared preferences and when the device restarts and you set the base of the chronometer you should do the followgin

```kotlin
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - millis)
```

where `millis` is the value you have in the preferences

Comment: This solution doesn't work, infact when you kill the app & go back to it, it display a totally different output